# Autowiring Not Working In Controller's Form Handling Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing my first Spring MVC app but I'm stuck on a certain exception.

The application has an Offer class, which has a private member of type User which is obviously another class.

I am using annotation configuration. I have a sys out in both classes constructors. I can see that for all occasions an offer object is created, a user object is also created so the autowiring works.

However, this is not the case in the controller's doCreate method. An offer object is passed into it to validate and bind to a HTML form but Spring doesn't create its user object.

Therefore, I get a NullPointerException at this line:

```
offer.getUser().setUsername(username);
```

So, why does Spring not create the Offer object's dependent User object in this case when it works fine in all other cases where the Offer object is used. What is affecting this behaviour?

Controller class (the offending method is at the end)

```
package com.offers.controllers;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.offers.dao.Offer;
import com.offers.service.OffersService;

@Controller
public class OffersController {

    private OffersService offersService;

    @Autowired
    public void setOffersService(OffersService offersService) {
        this.offersService = offersService;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/offers")
    public String showOffers(Model model){

        //offersService.throwTestException();

        List<Offer> offers = offersService.getCurrent();

        model.addAttribute("offers", offers);

        return "offers";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/createoffer")
    public String createOffer(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("offer", new Offer());
        return "createoffer";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/docreate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doCreate(Model model, @Valid Offer offer, BindingResult result, Principal principal) {


        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            return "createoffer";

        } 

        String username = principal.getName();

        offer.getUser().setUsername(username);
        offersService.create(offer);

        return "offercreated";

    }


}
```

Offer class (user setter method is immediately after the constructors)

```
package com.offers.dao;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.offers.validation.HasSpace;

@Component
public class Offer {

    // MEMBERS
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @HasSpace
    @Size(min = 5, max = 100, message = "The text must be between 5 and 100 characters.")
    private String text;


    private User user;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Offer() {

        System.out.println("************* offer created");
    }

    public Offer(int id, User user, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Offer(String text, User user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.text = text;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS

    @Autowired
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public String getUsername(){
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((text == null) ? 0 : text.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((user == null) ? 0 : user.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Offer other = (Offer) obj;
        if (text == null) {
            if (other.text != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!text.equals(other.text))
            return false;
        if (user == null) {
            if (other.user != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!user.equals(other.user))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Offer [id=" + id + ", text=" + text + ", user=" + user + "]";
    }



}
```

User class

```
package com.offers.dao;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.offers.validation.ValidEmail;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class User {

    // MEMBERS

    @NotBlank(message="Username cannot be blank")
    @Size(min=8, max=15)
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\w{8,}$", message="Username can only consists of numbers, letters and underscore")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message="Password cannot be blank")
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\S+$", message="Password must not contain spaces")
    @Size(min=8, max=15, message="Password must be between 8 and 15 characters long")
    private String password;

    @ValidEmail
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=2, max=60)
    private String name;

    private boolean enabled = false;
    private String authority;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public User() {
        System.out.println("************* user created");
    }

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled, String authority, String email, String name) {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.authority = authority;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;

    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((authority == null) ? 0 : authority.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (enabled ? 1231 : 1237);
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (authority == null) {
            if (other.authority != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!authority.equals(other.authority))
            return false;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (enabled != other.enabled)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (username == null) {
            if (other.username != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [username=" + username + ", email=" + email + ", name=" + name + ", enabled=" + enabled + ", authority=" + authority + "]";
    }


}
```

Servlet XML Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.offers"></context:component-scan>

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**" />


    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="com.offers.messages.messages"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
    </bean>

    <bean id="TilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/default.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

OffersService class

```
package com.offers.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.offers.dao.Offer;
import com.offers.dao.OfferDao;

@Service("offersService")
public class OffersService {

    private OfferDao offerDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setOffersDao(OfferDao offersDao) {
        this.offerDao = offersDao;
    }


    public List<Offer> getCurrent(){

        return offerDao.getOffers();

    }


    public boolean create(Offer offer){

        return offerDao.create(offer);

    }


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NPE because your objects are decalred as `null` by default.

are you even calling your `setters` which has the `@Autowired` annotation?

you could just autowire the field instead

```
 @Autowired
 private OffersService offersService;

 @Autowired
 private OfferDao offerDao;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I removed the Autowired annotation from the setter and annotated the field instead, i.e. @Autowired private User user; but the User object is still not being generated with the Offer object and the NPE is still be thrown.